# AndroidPlot: How to reset LineAndPointFormatter graph to original after zooming

Tags: androidplot

Am using androidplot library to display static graphs using `LineAndPointFormatter` within my Android app. But now am facing some issue related to zoom i.e. As per the requirement after zooming the graph if user double taps on the graph, same time graph should go back to the original position/initial position. Check below the code snippet which am trying currently i.e.

```
public void resetZoom() {

    newMinX = 0f;
    newMaxX = 0f;

    fixBoundariesForZoom();
    setDomainBoundaries(newMinX, newMaxX, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
    redraw();
}  // With this code whenever user double taps on the graph same time graph is displaying blank means domain and range value is resetting to the original but line graph is not displaying.
```

Can anybody please help me or let me know some workaround to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in "reset" option.  You could go through the library source and come up with something hardcoded that restores the internal defaults but it would be a brittle solution since the built in defaults could change in a future release of the library.  My suggestion would be to explicitly define the boundaries etc. that you'd like to use as your default state in a method and invoke that both at startup and on reset.